# Concatenate a Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, derived

I am trying to create a derived column in my SSIS package that will concatenate some data that I have been doing manually.

My expression is this:

```
"FEI" + " " +  [SHIP TO WHSE] + " - " +  [SHIP TO WHSE - NAME]
```

I have a report that has a column labeled `SHIP TO WHSE` and another labeled `SHIP TO WHSE - NAME`. In excel I usually create a new column and add FEI to the column and then concatenate the data in another new column to create a single name for a report. I would like to build this in SQL and automate its creation.

The above expression I thought would work to concatenate the data but it's not. The outcome should look like this.

```
FEI 3112 - Sandy
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

The error message is telling me that the data types are incompatible for the " + " to work.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a data conversion before the Derived column. It was the Branch Number that was causing the issue, I converted it to match the rest and it worked.